# Using SSRS in Visual Studio I am trying to join two different datasets using a date

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssms

I am receiving the following error

> "uses a lookup function with an expression that returned a data type that is not valid for the lookup function.  The data type must be an RDL Variant type"

when trying to use the following expression to match on a date value. Is there a better way to match on a date value? I made sure both values are data type date in my stored procedure, and refreshed the fields, in SSSRS prior to the preview.

```
=Lookup(Fields!Shipweek.Value,
Fields!Ship_Week.Value, 
Fields!PalletCount, "Reporting_sp_Forecast_LP_Shipped")
```

Comment: Try Fields!PalletCount.Value

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find an alternative solution by including the desired field in my original stored procedure using a left join on the date value the values were both data type date. it was no longer necessary to perform the Lookup, in Visual Studio SSRS.